# jQuery how to replace className of a href and click that sametime to run the function

Tags: jquery, click, classname

I have a href link is as below

```
<a href="#" class="add_encounter">Add</a>
```

on  `$(document).ready` i run this function is as below

```
$('.add_encounter').click(function(event) {
    add_encounter(encounters); 
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

on add_encounter function i changed class name of ahref from add_encounter to encounter encounterSubmitter and wants to click that same to run other function but when i click the
link it runs the function and change the classname to encounterSubmitter and change back to same class i.e. add_enounter

```
function add_encounter(encounters) {
     if ($('.add_encounter').text() == "Add"){        
        $('.add_encounter').removeClass().addClass("encounterSubmitter")
     } 
    $('.encounterSubmitter').click(function(event) {save(); event.preventDefault();}); 
}
```

save function is as below

```
  function save() {
    var encounter = $('#name').val();
    var key = $('#encounterKey').val();
    if (key == '') {
      key = null
    }
   if (encounter == ''){
 cancel_encounter() 
   }
}
```

cancel_encounter is as below

```
function cancel_encounter() {     
        $('.encounterSubmitter').removeClass().addClass("add_encounter")
        $('.add_encounter').text("Add")         
}
```

So it goes to save function checks the if condition and goes to cancel_encounter function
and changes the classname back to add_encounter

I know this question is little confusing, i hope however understand it or ever came across this kind of problem can able to give me the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="add my_encounter">Add</a>
```

JS

```
$('.my_encounter').bind('click', function(event) {

    if ((this).hasClass('add')){ //add_encounter
      //encounters ???
      $(this).removeClass('add').addClass("submitter")

    }
    else if ((this).hasClass('submitter')){  // save
      var encounter = $('#name').val(),
          key = $('#encounterKey').val();

      if (key == '') {
         key = null
      }
      if (encounter == ''){
        // cancel_encounter
        $(this)
           .removeClass("submitter")
           .addClass("add")
           .text("Add"); //?? where remove text "Add"
      }

    }

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I used your technique but here the problem is that i am using save function for saving the values if the encounter is not blank like this below

Comment: $('.my_encounter').bind('click', function(event) {
 if ($(this).hasClass('add')){$("#encountersList").slideUp("slow").hide();$(".encounterForm").show("slow");$('.encounterbutton').text("Cancel") $(this).text("Save") 
$('#top-half-header').text("Add Encounter")$(this).removeClass('add').addClass("submitter")}
 else if($(this).hasClass('submitter')){var encounter = $('#name').val(),key = $('#encounterKey').val();if (key == '') {key = null}if (encounter == ''){$(this.removeClass("submitter").addClass("add").text("+"); }else{encounters.save(key, encounter);}

    }

    event.preventDefault();
});

Comment: So in that case it saves the encounter twice if the $(.my_counter) clicked for second time.

Answer (score 0):

Not able to test this right but maybe this will work:

```
    $('.add_encounter').click(function(event) {
        add_encounter(encounters); 
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    function add_encounter(encounters) {
         if ($('.add_encounter').text() == "Add"){        
            $('.add_encounter').removeClass().addClass("encounterSubmitter")
         } 
    }

    $('.encounterSubmitter').live('click',function(event){
        save();
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    function save() {
        var encounter = $('#name').val();
        var key = $('#encounterKey').val();
        if (key == '') {
            key = null
        }
        if (encounter == ''){
            cancel_encounter() 
       }
    }

    function cancel_encounter() {     
        $('.encounterSubmitter').removeClass().addClass("add_encounter")
        $('.add_encounter').text("Add")         
    }
```

The problem was the save function being called by your add_encounter function. Therefore he would check your key and in turn call the cancel_encounter function resetting the link.

The live call will work even if your elements to bind to are loaded in after the javascript has loaded.